# Error enabling python-markdown extension for jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I downloaded and installed the `python-markdown` extension that lives inside the `nbextensions` repo here:

`jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/python-markdown/python-markdown.yaml`

```
jupyter-nbextension install python-markdown
```

At the end of the installation the following is posted:

```
Copying: /git/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/python-markdown/python-markdown-post.png -> /usr/local/share/jupyter/nbextensions/python-markdown/python-markdown-post.png

To initialize this nbextension in the browser every time the notebook (or other app) loads:

      jupyter nbextension enable <the entry point>
```

So I tried:

```
$jupyter nbextension enable python-markdown
```

Which gave:

```
Enabling notebook extension python-markdown...
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X python-markdown
```

I am uncertain how to proceed here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The short answer**
`jupyter nbextension enable python-markdown/main`

**The long answer**

The documentation seems to be not so clear but it states...

```
  jupyter nbextension enable <nbextension require path>
```

So it is imperative that we give the path to the `js` file related to the extension. To figure out what the actual file is, we should look for `jupyter` data paths

```
>>>foo$ jupyter --paths
config:
    /Users/foo/.jupyter
    /Users/foo/miniconda3/etc/jupyter
    /usr/local/etc/jupyter
    /etc/jupyter
data:
    /Users/foo/Library/Jupyter
    /Users/foo/miniconda3/share/jupyter
    /usr/local/share/jupyter
    /usr/share/jupyter
runtime:
    /Users/foo/Library/Jupyter/runtime
```

I looked in the `/Users/foo/Library/Jupyter` folder

```
>>>foo$ find  /Users/foo/Library/Jupyter -name python-markdown
/Users/foo/Library/Jupyter/nbextensions/python-markdown
>>>foo$ find /Users/foo/Library/Jupyter/nbextensions/python-markdown -name *js
/Users/foo/Library/Jupyter/nbextensions/python-markdown/main.js
```

Now I decided to use the path as `python-markdown/main`:-

```
>>>foo$ jupyter nbextension enable python-markdown/main
Enabling notebook extension python-markdown/main...
      - Validating: OK
>>>foo$ jupyter nbextension list
Known nbextensions:
  config dir: /Users/foo/.jupyter/nbconfig
    notebook section
      python-markdown  enabled 
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X python-markdown
      python-markdown/main  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
```

Edited the output above reflect more appropriate lines.

Note that my old `python-markdown` is still having problem validating but the new `python-markdown/main` is now enabled and validated.

Comment: nice sleuthing!